# unanswered vs. no answers

Tags: discussion, user-interface, unanswered-questions

I find the "Unanswered" tab and the "no answers" filter to be rather confusing.  Do I understand correctly that the "Unanswered" tab simply refers to questions that may have answers but not a *solution* accepted by the poster?  If so, can they not be renamed "Unsolved"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A questions counts as unanswered until is has (at least one) answer(s) with positive score or an accepted answer.

[Source on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)

We mix semantics of "answered" here; do we mean the OP got an answer, or there is an answer-type post? The naming of the "Unanswered" tab assumes the former meaning which I think is fair.